# Splitting a large file containing multiple molecules

Tags: bash, large-data

I have a file that contains 10,000 molecules. Each molecule is ending with keyword ***$$$$***. I want to split the main files into 10,000 separate files so that each file will have only 1 molecule. Each molecule have different number of lines. I have tried `sed` on `test_file.txt` as:

```
sed '/$$$$/q' test_file.txt > out.txt
```

input:

```
$ cat test_file.txt
ashu
vishu
jyoti
$$$$
Jatin
Vishal
Shivani
$$$$
```

output:

```
$ cat out.txt
ashu
vishu
jyoti
$$$$
```

I can loop it through whole main file to create 10,000 separate files but how to delete the last molecule that was just moved to new file from main file. Or please suggest if there is a better method for it, which I believe there is. Thanks.

```
Edit1:

$ cat short_library.sdf

untitled.cdx
csChFnd80/09142214492D

 31 34  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
    8.4660    6.2927    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    8.4660    4.8927    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.2124    2.0951    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.4249    2.7951    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  2  0  0  0  0
  2  3  1  0  0  0  0
 30 31  1  0  0  0  0
 31 26  1  0  0  0  0
M  END
>  <Mol_ID> (1)
1

>  <Formula> (1)
C22H24ClFN4O3

>  <URL> (1)
http://www.selleckchem.com/products/Gefitinib.html

$$$$
Dimesna.cdx
csChFnd80/09142214492D

 16 13  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
    2.4249    1.4000    0.0000 S   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    3.6415    2.1024    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    4.8540    1.4024    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    5.4904    1.7512    0.0000 Na  0  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0  0  0  0
  2  3  1  0  0  0  0
  1 14  2  0  0  0  0
M  END
>  <Mol_ID> (2)
2

>  <Formula> (2)
C4H8Na2O6S4


>  <URL> (2)
http://www.selleckchem.com/products/Dimesna.html

$$$$
```

Comment: What should the files be named? Should $$$$ also be included in the new files?

Comment: I'm not quite grasping how anything in the example input is a "molecule", but that probably doesn't matter.  This wouldn't be too hard to script directly in `bash`, without using any external utility such as `sed` or (more likely) `awk`.

Comment: @Cyrus files can be molecule1.sdf, molecule2.sdf ... molecule10000.sdf

Comment: @Cyrus yes $$$$ should also be included in new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple solution with standard `awk`:

```bash
LANG=C awk '
    { mol = (mol == "" ? $0 : mol "\n" $0) }
    /^\$\$\$\$\r?$/ {
        outFile = "molecule" ++fn ".sdf"
        print mol > outFile
        close(outFile) 
        mol = ""
    }
' input.sdf
```

Comment: thanks, it works good on sample input file (test_file.txt) but not on actual file (short_library.sdf). Can you please help, I have updated (Edit 1) the main post with the trim version(short_library.sdf) of main file which is too big to attach here.

Comment: @JatinKashyap The code should work with your edit, unless you got `CRLF` line endings; I updated my code to take care of that possibility.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It seems to work after I removed the special characters manually in molecules main file. Consequently, I believe following error was for special characters: $ sh test_file.sh
'wk: towc: multibyte conversion failure on: '��-deoxy-5-azacytidine).cdx

 input record number 1219, file 20220914-L1400-Natural-Product-Library.SDF
 source line number 3

Comment: So far I don't believe I will run into a problem because of removing those special characters (£®£©¶≈ etc.) but if do run into one, is there a quick solution for now?

Comment: @JatinKashyap I prepended a `LANG=C` to the command, that should ignore encoding issues

Answer (score 1):

This will do the whole job directly in `bash`:

**molsplit.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

filenum=0
end=1

while read -r line; do
    if [[ $end -eq 1 ]]; then
        end=0
        filenum=$((filenum + 1))
        exec 3>"molecule${filenum}.sdf"
    fi
    echo "$line" 1>&3
    if [[ "$line" = '$$$$' ]]; then
        end=1
        exec 3>&-
    fi
done
```

Input is read from stdin, though that would be easy enough to change.  Something like this:

```
./molsplit.sh < test_file.txt
```

---

**ADDENDUM**

From subsequent commentary, it seems that the input file being processed has Windows line endings, whereas the processing environment's native line ending format is UNIX-style.  In that case, if the line-termination style is to be preserved then we need to modify how the delimiters are recognized.  For example, this variation on the above will recognize any line that starts with `$$$$` as a molecule delimiter:

```
#!/bin/bash

filenum=0
end=1

while read -r line; do
    if [[ $end -eq 1 ]]; then
        end=0
        filenum=$((filenum + 1))
        exec 3>"molecule${filenum}.sdf"
    fi
    echo "$line" 1>&3
    case $line in
      '$$$$'*) end=1; exec 3>&-;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: thanks, it works good on sample input file (test_file.txt) but not on actual file (short_library.sdf). Can you please help, I have updated (Edit 1) the main post with the trim version(short_library.sdf) of main file which is too big to attach here.

Comment: @JatinKashyap, the script in this answer works fine for me on the additional example you added to the question.  What exactly "does not work" about it for you?

Comment: doing sh molsplit.sh < short_library.sdf output a file molecule1.sdf which is exact copy of short_library.sdf

Comment: Not for me, @JatinKashyap.  Best guess: your file has Windows line terminators, but you are processing it on Linux or maybe macOS.  In that case, the delimiter lines include a carriage-return character that is normally hidden from you, and which does not come across in the version posted in your question.  In that case, an important question arises: do you want to keep the Windows line endings?

Comment: Sounds plausible. I can blue $ signs at end of each line. Following is my terminal output> $file short_library.sdf
short_library.sdf: ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators

Comment: Can we keep Windows line endings? Thanks.

Comment: Updated, @JatinKashyap.  The new variation will work for both Windows and UNIX line endings, provided that all lines that *start with* `$$$$` are to be understood as delimiters.  (Including things like `$$$$1`, `$$$$ oops`, *etc*.)

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But I am not able to see the expected molecule and I guess that is because the function is changing the columns spaces in the resulting files, and these molecule files tend to be column space sensitive. Is there anyway we can keep the same white spaces throughout the whole content as they are in the main file(short_library.sdf).

Answer (score 1):

If you have `csplit` from GNU coreutils:

```
csplit -s -z -n5 -fmolecule test_file.txt '/^$$$$$/+1' '{*}'
```

Comment: @M : i think it's 4 `"$"`  instead of 5 ?

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto No. The first 4 `$`s are literal and the last one refers to end of line. This regular expression matches a line consisting of only 4 `$`s .

Comment: what flavor of regex is that, cuz i thought you need to escape the `$` to get the literals ? something like `/^[$]{4}$/` is probably what you're aiming for ?

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto In Extended Regular Expression notation, the `$` has to be quoted or bracketed to get a literal `$`. In Basic Regular Expression notation, it doesn't have to be, unless it is the last character in the expression or sub-expression. As far as I know, GNU `csplit` uses BRE, though I don't have a reference for that.

Comment: @M : if that's the case, then how can the regex engine determine where the end of string anchor is supposed to be ? you can refer to the `posix` spec on `BRE` : `https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_07`

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto See [9.3.8 BRE Expression Anchoring](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_08): _"A <dollar-sign> ( '$' ) shall be an anchor when used as the last character of an entire BRE. The implementation may treat a <dollar-sign> as an anchor when used as the last character of a subexpression"_ If it is not the last character of an expression then it is not anchor, thus not a special character (in BRE notation).

Comment: `echo '$$$$'  | grep -e '^$$$\($$\|$\)$'` - this example fails, and that's the problem about - "may treat" - so according to the spec, the second case in the alternation *may* be treated as an anchor, but they can do whatever they like, then how can anyone rely on them ?

Comment: even this fails : `echo '$$$$'  | grep -e '^$$$\($\)$'`  - no alternation at all this time, but simply grouping the 4th `"$"`  in its own group would fail it

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto My regex in the answer doesn't contain a sub-expression, so it doesn't have those problems. It appears that the use of `$` as a last character in a _sub-expression_ may be problematic indeed in a few contexts.

Answer (score 1):

The same statement that sets the current output file name also closes the previous one. `close(_)^_` here is same as `close(_)^0`, which ensures the filename always increments for the next one, even if the `close()` action resulted in an error.

—  if the output file naming scheme allows for leading-edge zeros, then change that bit to `close(_)^(_<_)`, which ***ALWAYS*** results in a 1, for any possible string or number, including all forms of zero, the empty string, `inf`-inities, and `nan`s.

> ```
> mawk2 'BEGIN { getline __<(_ = "/dev/null")
>               ORS = RS = "[$][$][$][$][\r]?"(FS = RS)
>                __*= gsub("[^$\n]+", __, ORS) 
>       } NF  {
>             print > (_ ="mol" (__+=close(_)^_) ".txt") }' test_file.txt
> ```

The first part about `getline` from `/dev/null` neither sets `$0 | NF` nor modifies `NR | FNR`, but it's existence ensures the first time `close(_)` is called it wouldn't error out.

```
gcat -n mol12345.txt

     1  Shivani
     2  jyoti
     3  Shivani
     4  $$$$
```

it was reasonably speedy - from `5.60 MB` synthetic test file created `187,710` files in `11.652 secs`.